# Why my answer have grayed out?

Tags: support, bug, status-bydesign, answers

[My answer](https://islam.stackexchange.com/a/43995/24518) is grayed out? When mouse over on the answer, it's color been normal(Black) again while the mouse pointer is over on my answer.

Why because my answer show with gray and pale, now?

How is it shown tho another users?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The system automatically fades low scoring answers to prevent them from drawing focus away from the high scoring answers, which are presumed to be more useful. If readers still want to read them, they can mouseover the answer and it'll unfade to be more legible. It's a feature, not a bug.